# Cannot fetch the name,username and password

Tags: php, mysql

When I try to login it shows Incorrect user details. Although the data is getting inserted but not getting fetched.
Following are my two PHP files.

Register.php

```
<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("mysql.hostinger.in","name","password","u721174658_swap");


$name = $_POST["name"];

$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];

$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO `user` (name,username, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "sss", $name,$username, $password);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);



mysqli_stmt_close($statement);

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

FetchUserData.php

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("mysql.hostinger.in","name","password","u721174658_swap");



$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];

$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ss", $username, $password);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $userID, $name,$username, $password);

$user = array();

while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
    $user["name"] = $name;

    $user["username"] = $username;
    $user["password"] = $password;
}

echo json_encode($user);
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: **Do not store passwords in plain text**.

Comment: Also - shouldn't you be assigning `$user` in your while loop? `while($user = mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){`

Comment: @andrewsi- tried doing that.. still problem persists

Comment: as per what @andrewsi suggested. However, you will need to remove the `$user = array();` if using that. Plus, check for errors on the query http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: Consult the manual http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php you may also need to do `$user["username"][0] = $username;` or similar. Or even `$user[username] = $username;`

Comment: Does anything echo if you do `while ( mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement) ) { echo $user["name"] = $username; echo $username; }` ?

Answer (score 0):

use to fetch the following way and session start

```
    while($row= mysql_fetch_array($statement){
    $name = $row['name'];
}
```

Comment: The user is using `mysqli_` - `mysql_fetch_array` won't work.